# Erro ao inserir icon em JLabel

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, gui

Estou fazendo uma interface gráfica em um projeto java (maven) e estou tendo um problema ao tentar colocar um icon no JLabel.

[image: inserindo icon ao JLabel]

E quando eu executo o projeto dá o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro]

Como estou utilizando a GUI do netebeans, não tem como eu editar o código que é  gerado pelo próprio IDE.
Eu testei a mesma interface em um projeto comum java (sem maven) e funcionou normalmente, alguém sabe porque isso está acontecendo somente em projetos maven?
Dei uma pesquisada e achei alguns outros problemas similares a projetos maven, adicionando icons em botões etc.

Comment: Como pode ser visto no primeiro print, não está sendo setado o icon nas propriedades(A direita). Cheque se não está setando pra um componente diferente do JLabel ou, na pior das hipoteses, remova a referencia do icon na gui e faça isso manualmente, por código.

Comment: Não estava setado nas propriedades porque eu ainda estava adicionando. Após clicar no botão "OK" o nome da icon estaria ali nas propriedades.

Comment: Entendi, adicione um [mcve] na pergunta, para que seja possivel analisa e reproduzir o problema.